# angular 2 replace current element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

i would like to replace the current element when doing routing instead of appending it. For instance my code is the following:

```
<router-outlet>
    <div class="=row" style="height:30%"></div>
    <div class="=row">
        <a routerLink="search" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="width:90%;height:20%;margin-left:5%">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search1
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="=row" style="height:30%"></div>
    <div class="=row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="width:90%;height:20%;margin-left:5%">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Search2
        </button>
    </div>
</router-outlet>
```

However, it ends up like the following screenshot:
[image]

The search text is from the searchCOmponent routing. what i want is when i click search1, search 1 and search 2 to be gone and replaced by the "testing search" text loaded from searchComponent. that's why i put the "route-outlet" tag as the parent tag. I was hoping it replaces the entire body. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct usage of the router outlet. It should not have any content. Rather, the router populates the router outlet automatically, giving you the result you are looking for.

See the docs for more information: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#sts=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts%20(appRoutes)